# How to write a declarative for loop c++14

Tags: c++, range, c++17

Is there a way to write a declarative style for loop in C++14

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2) {
    // ... some code
}
```

The closest I have found is using boost is

```
for(auto i : irange(1,10,2)){
     // .... some code
}
```

Is there a c++14/17 standards way of achieving the same effect?
I was trying std::make_integer_sequence() as a possible starting point, but couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: What's wrong with `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2)`?

Comment: `make_integer_sequence` is the equivalent of what you want if you were doing template metaprogramming instead of what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: @cpplearner  because that is not declarative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a standard way of iterating over a numerical range as you desire. C++14 however allows you to create your own utilities very easily.

---

Approach one: **numerical range**.

Here's an **unoptimized quickly-hacked-together** example:

```
template <typename T>
struct num_range_itr
{
    T _value, _step;

    num_range_itr(T value, T step) 
        : _value{value}, _step{step} 
    {
    }

    auto operator*() const { return _value; }
    auto operator++() { _value += _step; }

    auto operator==(const num_range_itr& rhs) const { return _value == rhs._value; }
    auto operator!=(const num_range_itr& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
};

template <typename T>
struct num_range
{
    T _start, _end, _step;

    num_range(T start, T end, T step) 
        : _start{start}, _end{end}, _step{step} 
    {
    }

    auto begin() const { return num_range_itr<T>{_start, _step}; }
    auto end() const { return num_range_itr<T>{_end, _step}; }
};

template <typename T>
auto make_range(T start, T end, T step = 1)
{
    return num_range<T>{start, end, step};
}
```

The code above can be used as follows:

```
for(auto i : make_range(0, 10, 2))
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}

// Prints: 0 2 4 6 8
```

---

Approach two: **higher-order function**.

Here's an **unoptimized quickly-hacked-together** example:

```
template <typename T, typename TF>
auto for_range(T start, T end, T step, TF f)
{
    for(auto i = start; i < end; i += step)
    {
        f(i);
    }

    return f;
}
```

The code above can be used as follows:

```
for_range(0, 10, 2, [](auto i){ std::cout << i << " "; });

// Prints: 0 2 4 6 8
```

---

The code can be found [on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9nzayM8lWQR8O6sC).

If you want to use these utilities in real projects, you need to carefully write them in order to support multiple types safely, avoid unintentional signed/unsigned conversions, avoid invalid ranges, and make sure they get optimized away.

Comment: I like that you show that it is not so scary to implement something like this yourself.

Comment: Note that `num_range_itr` is useful for far more than num ranges if you divorce `step` from the `value` field's type.  Examine what happens when `value` is an iterator!  Now do `make_range( begin(vec), end(vec), 1 )`: you iterate over the iterators of `vec`.  This also permits optimizing for compile-time constant `step=1` by making `step` of type `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>`.

Comment: I like the higher order version. That could be useful for a range (no pun) of iterations

Answer (score 0):

`std::integer_sequence` will help you only if you know the size at the compilation time. I personally hate pre C++11 for-loop. It is quite easy to make a mistake by writing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
  for (int j = 0; j < m; ++i) // very hard to spot
```

I use my little helper seq_t class, which I believe exactly what you need. Please note `typename std::enable_if`. It is to make sure it will be only used for integral types (`int, uint8_t, long long` etc.), but you can't use it for `double` or `float`. You can use it in three different ways:

```
for (int i : seq(1, 10))    // [1, 10), step 1
for (int i : seq(1, 10, 2)) // [1, 10), step 2
for (int i : seq(10))       // [0, 10), step 1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type >
class seq_t
{
  T m_begin;
  T m_end;
  T m_step;

public:
  class iterator
  {
    T m_curr;
    T m_step;

    constexpr iterator(T curr, T step)
      : m_curr(curr), m_step(step)
    {
    }

    constexpr iterator(T end)
      : m_curr(end), m_step(0)
    {
    }

    friend class seq_t;

  public:
    constexpr iterator& operator++()
    {
      m_curr += m_step;
      return *this;
    }

    constexpr T operator*() const noexcept
    {
      return m_curr;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const noexcept
    {
      return this->m_curr != rhs.m_curr;
    }
  };

  constexpr iterator begin(void) const noexcept
  {
    return iterator(m_begin, m_step);
  }

  constexpr iterator end(void) const noexcept
  {
    return iterator(m_end, m_step);
  }

  constexpr seq_t(T begin, T end, T step) noexcept
    : m_begin(begin), m_end(end), m_step(step)
  {
  }
};

template<typename T>
inline seq_t<T>
constexpr seq(T begin, T end, T step = 1) noexcept
{
  return seq_t<T>(begin, end, step);
}

template<typename T>
inline seq_t<T>
constexpr seq(T end) noexcept
{
  return seq_t<T>(T{0}, end, 1);
}
```